# CSS Responsive BG Images

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a full width parallax site and having an issue getting background images for sections to scale properly.

How would I get a full width image in desktop view to shrink down and contain a 100% width but the height shrink and image contain proportions to fit the width?  The problem I am having is I can't set a background container to have a max height.

I'm really looking for a way for the height to shrink from 100% down when the viewport keeps getting smaller so that the focus of the picture isn't lost and maintains proportions just like a responsive image would.

I have tried background-size: contain as well but even then the container has to a have a fixed height which has to change while the background image shrinks because otherwise the image won't be fluid with the container.

```
#main-photo {
background-image: url("images/main.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
margin-top: 130px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

If I remove the height obviously nothing is rendered in the browser and max-height doesn't work like it would for responsive images.

Can someone please help me with this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background-size: contain` instead of `background-size: cover`. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4yh0yns/)

```
#main-photo {
    background-image: url('images/main.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want the height to be 100% in smaller viewports.  I want it to be a fluid height just like with a responsive image.

Comment: Found a solution. See below please.

Comment: My solution does allow the height of the image to be fluid. If you minimize the width then the height decreases to the ratio of the width. It is 100% of the viewport, so when the screen is smaller it is too. But, if your solution works too, or better for you then that is great and nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a padding trick that adds height and allows the image to maintain its aspect ratio.  Thank You!

Just add

```
padding-bottom: %here
```

You won't need to specify a height for the background image only a 100% width.

Here is a great article. http://www.outsidethebracket.com/responsive-web-design-fluid-background-images/